# rvm: command not found from cap deploy

Tags: deployment, installation, rvm, capistrano, bundle

Hope this question helps someone, but I'm interested in the answer anyway. I had this error when running

```
cap deploy
```

among the other output it gave:

```
rvm: command not found
```

I googled and tried many hacks, nothing worked except this:

```
run "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && cd #{deploy_to} && bundle && ..."
```

That way I can execute anything like bundle etc. Problem is I have to specify it in the beginning of each run, or just as you see, separate commands in a single line with &&.

My question is, how can I make it work correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use RVM - Capistrano integration gem => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#readme